# Most effective way of making a java game loop

Tags: java, loops, delay, infinite-loop

I'm searching for the best way, to make a loop have an delay in a game.
Is it `Thread.sleep(...);` or just checking the time elapsed since the last tick?
I heard, that `Thread.sleep(...)` was to inaccurate.

Comment: That very much depends on your requirements. Please turn to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here. Not exactly like this.

Comment: Pretty much the same. But as thread sleep is given to you, why not using it?

Comment: [This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53805/java-2d-game-programming-different-approaches-to-make-a-game-loop) might be helpful to you.

Comment: Have a search over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, there's lots of info on game loops and such...

Comment: If precision is important, then you can use a mixed sleep() and System.nanoTime()-difference approach. First sleep a little, then run one of those nice energy consuming processor-heating manual wait loops for the rest of the time.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, if you are delaying between frames of a game, `Thread.sleep` is fine. 
You can use it, along with calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` to decide how much time to delay between frames.

Example:

```
while(!quit) {
    long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    update();
    render();

    long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
    long sleepTime = DELAY_PERIOD - timeTaken;

    if (sleepTime >= 0) {
        try{Thread.sleep(sleepTime);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

where `DELAY_PERIOD` is the total amount of milliseconds you want a frame to take. Also, you shouldn't need to handle the `InterruptedException` unless you specifically program your application to use Interrupts.

This example allows the delay length to vary based on the time spent in `update()` and `render()` functions. If the update or render takes longer than `DELAY_PERIOD`, it doesn't wait at all.